# How to change "There are no items to show" message for Item Display Template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, display-template, content-search-web-part

We are using SP2016 enterprise and I am trying to customize a Item Display template for a Content Search web part.

My work is based on existing template under Master Page Gallery > Display Templates > Content web part (subfolder) > `Item_LargePicture.html` .

I searched online and several tutorial suggest look for the line with

```
if (ctx.ClientControl.get_shouldShowNoResultMessage())
```

but this line is not exist in  `Item_LargePicture.html`.

I have tried inserting the above line and sample content but it is not working. My Content search web part always returning `There are no items to show.`

P.S. my custom template works great when there is item to show. The only problem is when result = 0 the error message is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Content Search Webpart there are 2 display templates. They are `Item Display Template` and `Control Display Template`.

[image]

> There are two primary types of display templates:
>
> Control templates determine the overall structure of how the results
> are presented. Includes lists, lists with paging, and slide shows.
>
> Item templates determine how each result in the set is displayed.
> Includes images, text, video, and other items.
>
> (Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates)

The file `Item_LargePicture.html` is item template. In order to change `There are no items to show` message we need to modify a Control template. Therefore I make a copy of `Control_List.html` and customize it as a new Control Template to solve my problem.